# Application running in Docker does not see the file

Tags: java, docker, ubuntu

A text document is being processed in my jar.

The file location specified in the code is `/home/ubuntu/R.txt`.

If I run the jar through the ubuntu console `java -jar 1.jar`, then everything starts without problems: the jar file recognizes the document at `/home/ubuntu/R.txt`.

However, if I run the same jar via `docker build -t fb:1.1-SNAPSHOT .` and `docker run -p 8080:8080 fb:1.1-SNAPSHOT`, then the jar file gives an error about the absence of the file `R.txt`.

I run it from the same directory.

It contains a Dockerfile, a jar file, and a text document.

Tell me how to correctly specify the location of the file for Docker or where is it better to transfer the file?

Comment: How does the file get into the container?  If the application's main purpose is to read and write local files, is Docker's filesystem isolation a major barrier, and would it make more sense to use a host JVM without Docker involved?  Can you edit the question to include a [mcve]?

Comment: As @DavidMaze said, probably you shouldn't use docker if the application should process local files. You may copy the files into the container, but the container is much like a virtual machine and doesn't have access to the files in the host machine.